# Is it possible to complete the challenges in the Epilogue chapters and beyond?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I'm steadily working my way through the challenges and collectables of the RDR2 world while I have chapter 5 on pause (I'm basically ignoring the main story mission for now).

There's a bunch of stuff/land to the west of Blackwater that's currently blocked off to me, so I assume that I can carry on with my challenges later on in the game.

Is there a point in the game where the challenge/collectable strands of game completion stop, or can I carry on with the story until completion and carry on with the challenges after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can complete the challenges after you finish the game. And while I haven't tried this myself, some people claim that certain challenges are impossible to complete before the epilogue, as you need access to the area that is locked for most of the game.

There are reasons to prefer finishing the side missions and free roaming before the epilogue, or the other way around. They're inevitably a rather major spoiler:

> You play the epilogue as a different character, so if you prefer Arthur it makes sense to do most stuff before you end chapter 6.